# Есть равносильное действие transform.forward только для физического движения?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Transform.forward это по факту телепортация объекта вперед по оси Z, из-за телепортации гравитация перестает работать должным образом. Нужна **равносильная замена**, только **физическая**.

```
using UnityEngine;
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(CapsuleCollider))]
public class mainCharacterMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
private Vector3 moveVector;

public float speedCharacter = 5f;
public float ternVelocity = 3f;

private Rigidbody _rbMainCharacter;

void Start()
{
    _rbMainCharacter = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    MoveLogic();
}

private void MoveLogic()
{
    moveVector.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * ternVelocity; 
    moveVector.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speedCharacter;


    
    _rbMainCharacter.velocity = transform.forward *  moveVector.z; //проблема
    _rbMainCharacter.AddTorque(transform.up * moveVector.x);



}
}
```

Comment: Это не телепортация, а нормализованный вектор направления, и ты его можешь использовать где захочешь, даже в физике. Самое смешное, что нты используешь точно такой же вектор transform.up только другое направление... а вообще для передвижения персонажа считается плохой практикой использовать  Rigidbody и CapsuleCollider, пользуйся лучше CharacterController. Вот ссылочка, для ознакомления https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html

Comment: Спасибо, я только изучаю Unity, и хотел бы сделать все правильно. Т.е как делают в компаниях. Рассмотрю документацию.

Answer (score 0):

Написано с методом AddForce() - приложить силу.

Для теста нужны в иерархии объекты Plane и Sphere.

Базовое движение шара:

```
using UnityEngine;


[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed = 10f;

    private Rigidbody _rb;


    void Start()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }


    // все действия с физикой в FixedUpdate
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovementLogic();
    }


    private void MovementLogic()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        _rb.AddForce(movement * Speed);
    }

}
```

Comment: Этот код только для передвижения вперед назад, лево право. Transform.forward в свою очередь толкает по оси z объекта, а не сцены. Т.е, в какую сторону повернуть объект, туда он и движется вперед.

Comment: Это четкое физическое движение шара.